# MongoDB Given a list of keys, get all matching docs and create new docs for non-matching keys

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization, database

Say I've got a collections of User documents that are indexed by email address. Given a list of email addresses, I need to:

```
1. Get each User doc whose email is in that list
2. Create a new User doc for each email in the list for which no User exists.
```

I can easily solve the first problem with a $in query, but I was hoping there was some way to get the $in query to return a list of emails that are not found in the DB. Then I can efficiently insert new docs. Otherwise, I have to loop over the docs to find which emails weren't picked up.

What's the most efficient way to accomplish both of the above tasks? Is there a fast way to batch insert new User docs from a set of unique emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was hoping there was some way to get the $in query to return a list of emails that are not found in the DB.

You could use [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/). Unfortunately, `$ne` and `$nin` [can't make good use of indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#using-ne-and-nin-in-a-query-is-slow-why), so that might not be your best bet (but maybe worth a try).

The best approach probably depends on your 'cache-miss-rate', but this should work if the number of existing matches isn't too high (pseudocode)

```
var emails;
var matchingMails = users.find({"email" : {$in : emails}}, {"email":1, "_id":0});
var newEmails = emails.subtract(matchingMails); // set difference
db.batchInsert(createUsersFromEmails(newEmails));
```

i.e.

1. Find all users with matching email addresses using `$in`. Make sure to only return the email field itself so the [query is covered](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries) (i.e. MongoDB only looks at the indexes themselves and doesn't have to scan the documents)
2. Remove all emails from the list that are already in the database (simple string operation, fast)
3. Batch insert newly created users (i.e. create a list or array of user objects client-side and send them to the db)

This limits the number of round-trips to the database. Since the query is index convered, it will be very, very fast unless your RAM is exhausted and the index doesn't fit into RAM anymore.

It's wise to use a unique index on the email address and allow the batch insert to complete even if individual inserts fail in case somebody signed up in between or there is another thread running this code.

The number of elements for the `$in` query shouldn't be too high, somewhere from 1,000 to 10,000 as a rule of thumb.

Comment: Awesome, this is the path I was going down. How would your answer change if I wanted to get back the entire document for matching users?

Comment: well, not much. Just have all data delivered. That way, the query won't be covered, but if you need the data, you need it. In step 2 you can proceed as before, only you need a simple projection like `x -> x.email` when doing the set subtract.